# Parentheses change code execution

Tags: purescript

I'm trying to `attempt` an `Aff` computation. Consider the following code:

```
result <-
    pool # withPool \connection -> do
        execute_ ("insert into user (email, password) values ('"
            <> unwrap userInfo.email <> "', '" <> unwrap userInfo.password <> "')")
            connection
    # attempt
```

The resulting `Aff` of `attempt` is later run using `runAff`.

Despite using `attempt`, the error in `withPool` is propagated to the error handler of `runAff`.

However, if parentheses are added around the `Aff` being attempted, the error is "caught" as expected:

```
result <-
    (pool # withPool \connection -> do
        execute_ ("insert into user (email, password) values ('"
            <> unwrap userInfo.email <> "', '" <> unwrap userInfo.password <> "')")
            connection)
    # attempt
```

What am I missing here and why is the behavior of these two code snippets different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first snippet is equivalent to

```
result <-
  pool # withPool (\connection -> do
    execute_ ...
    # attempt)
```

and not

```
result <-
  pool # (withPool \connection -> do
            execute_ ...)
       # attempt
```